# Configuring OSGI Enroute REST application to allow async requests

Tags: java, rest, jetty, osgi, enroute

I am currently trying to configure a REST application to enable Server-side events to be sent to a client using `EventSource`. Currently I am running into an `IllegalStateException` when attempting to open an asynchronous connection to a REST request which appears to be the result of the server not being configured to allow asynchronous requests.

Some code

```
@RequireBootstrapWebResource(resource="css/bootstrap.css")
@RequireWebServerExtender
@RequireHttpImplementation
@RequireConfigurerExtender
@Component(name="my.web", property={"debug=true"})
public final class MyApplication implements REST
{
   public void getBatching(RESTRequest request)
   {
      User user = authenticate(request);

      HttpServletResponse response = request._response();
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
      response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      try
      {
         AsyncContext async = (AsyncContext)request._request().startAsync();
         async.addListener(new InternalAsyncListener());
         sseConnectionMap.put(UUID.randomUUID(), async);

         response.flushBuffer();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Message=" + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @Activate
   void activate(ComponentContext cc, BundleContext bc, Map<String, Object> config)
   {
      System.out.println(this.getClass() + " started");

      if ("true".equals(config.get("debug")))
      {
         debug = true;
      }

      System.out.println("Link Start");
   }
}
```

Currently that prints the following:

```
Message=null
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:314)
at my.application.MyApplication.getBatching(WebApplication.java:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at osgi.enroute.rest.simple.provider.Function.invoke(Function.java:203)
at osgi.enroute.rest.simple.provider.RestMapper.execute(RestMapper.java:333)
at osgi.enroute.rest.simple.provider.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
at my.application.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:124)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:61)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where `authenticate()` currently modifies headers when in **debug** mode to allow for CORS while developing the application and attempts to obtain a `User` from a token passed in the `Authorization` header... however even if I put the `startAsync()` line above that I still get the same `IllegalStateException` so I don't think it's an issue of header modification.

Some googling has brought up that the ISE on that particular line `ServletRequestWrapper.java:314` indicates that the underlying Felix/Jetty server is not set up to allow asynchronous requests.

I also tried to simply set the header to `text/event-stream` and continue to write to the response but of course it was closed upon exiting the REST method.

Further investigation has provided other solutions, including running a second servlet which is configured for handling asynchronous requests and binding that to a separate URL pattern. That is, of course, it's own effort, and I'm unsure of how well multiple servlets will play together. Preferably I would like to be able to just open asynchronous responses from the one Enroute application.

If it is possible to configure the enroute application to allow asynchronous responses, what is the setting I am messing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh... found the answer while having difficulties getting an `@WebServlet` to start up and kept coming back to Whiteboard. A search for 'whiteboard async Java' brought up the `HttpWhiteboardConstants` setting: `HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_ASYNC_SUPPORTED`:

```
@Component(..., property={...,
     HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_ASYNC_SUPPORTED+"=true", ...}...)
```

This, however, did not work on the `@Component` implementing `REST` , instead I was only able to get it to work in a separate component as follows:

```
@RequireHttpImplementation
@Component(name="sse", property={
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN+"=/sse/*",
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_ASYNC_SUPPORTED+"=true",
    HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_ASYNC_SUPPORTED+"=true"},
    service=Servlet.class)
public final class ServerSideEventServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
       throws ServletException, IOException
   {
   }
}
```

and this `Servlet` is started parallel to the one in my question. When I tried to pull this configuration over to the `REST` server, I still got the same exception. It could be because the `request` is touched outside of the REST method, which does make sense.